# TextViews doesn't display any text

Tags: android, textview

In rare situations our application goes into a state where no letters are displayed. Screenshots are attached to demonstrate this. On the first is the application in normal state, on  the second with letters disappeared (http://pic.pschstavebni.cz/limigo.png). It seems that all the TextViews (updated in code) does’nt display any text. This happens rarely and we can’t reproduce it in test environment. For most users, the application works fine, for few of the users this state sometimes occurs. After a device restart the application works normally. Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Users have Samsung Note 8 tablets. Layout is done using fragments in v4 support library. 
All TextViews have default value in xml layout. I checked code for uncaught exceptions and OutOfMemory problems, but without success.

Comment: its seems like listview you need to check the adapter.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, but that looks like a listView on your left.  I'd suspect that either there's a problem in a custom adaptor mapping data to it, a problem in the data backing your adaptor, or in your getview function.  Since the right fragment looks to be a detail of the selection on the left, that makes me think more the adaptor or data backing it than the getView.

Comment: Thank you for tips. We don’t think the problem is in the adapter, because it’s present not only in the ListView but in the detail fragment too.It seems like it happens in all TextViews, for which is the text set in code by setText method. Text assigned directly in layout is displayed normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved after upgrading to a newer version of android.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the elements on the XML layout have a good alignment.